# Check if index in array exists from string

Tags: php, arrays

do you know how to test, whether an index, based on what we pass in a string, exists in an array?

Assume the following code:

```
<?php

$myArray = [
    "elemOne" => "valueElemOne",
    "elemTwo" => [
        "elemTwoOne" => "valueElemTwoOne",
        "elemTwoTwo" => [
            "elemThreeOne" => "valueElemThreeOne",
            "elemThreeTwo" => "valueElemThreeTwo",
        ],
    ],
];
```

Now, I have a string `$myString = "elemTwo/elemTwoTwo/elemThreeThree"`. What I want to do with `$myString` is somewhat format it in a way, so I could check

```
<?php

if(isset($myArray['elemTwo']['elemTwoTwo']['elemThreeThree'])) {
    // maybe do something
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

Naturally in my case this would return false, as the index `"elemThreeThree"` does not exist within my array. I tried splitting the string, tried to format as `[elemTwo][elemTwoTwo][elemThreeThree]` and then evaluating it, but nothing really worked.

Do you think of a possible approach that could help me?

Answer (score 1):

simple solution could be

```
  <?php
     $arr = array('hello'=>array('world'=>array('in'=>'jo')));
     $myString = "hello/world/inf";

     function checkString($string, array $search_array) {
        $test = explode('/',$string);
        foreach($test as $key) {
           if(isset($search_array[$key])) $search_array = $search_array[$key];
           else return false;
        }
        return true;
     }
     var_dump(checkString($myString,$arr));
     die;
```

The Output of the function will true or false

Answer (score 0):

Why did splitting it not work?
Is there something wrong with this?

```
<?php
$arrayTest = array(
    "arrayOne" => "string", 
    "arrayTwo" => array(
        "arrayThree"    => "string",
        "arrayFour"     => array("winner" => "me")
    )
);

var_dump(expanded_key_exists($arrayTest, "arrayOne"));
var_dump(expanded_key_exists($arrayTest, "arrayTwo"));
var_dump(expanded_key_exists($arrayTest, "arrayTwo/arrayThree"));
var_dump(expanded_key_exists($arrayTest, "arrayTwo/arrayThree/arrayTwenty"));
var_dump(expanded_key_exists($arrayTest, "arrayTwo/arrayFour"));
var_dump(expanded_key_exists($arrayTest, "arrayTwo/arrayFour/winner"));

if(expanded_key_exists($arrayTest, "arrayTwo/arrayFour/winner")){
    echo "The winner is: " . expanded_array_key($arrayTest, "arrayTwo/arrayFour/winner");
}

function expanded_key_exists($array, $key){
    $arrayKeys = explode("/", $key);
    foreach($arrayKeys as $someKey){
        if(is_array($array) && array_key_exists($someKey, $array)){
            $array = $array[$someKey];
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

function expanded_array_key($array, $key){
    $arrayKeys = explode("/", $key);
    foreach($arrayKeys as $someKey){
        if(is_array($array) && array_key_exists($someKey, $array)){
            $array = $array[$someKey];
        }else{
            return null;
        }
    }
    return $array;
}
?>
```

Comment: The output btw: bool(true) bool(true) bool(true) bool(false) bool(true) bool(true) The winner is: me

Comment: Thanks a lot Christian I could not wrap my head around the problem.